# How can i use modern toolkit in Ext.Net Mvc

Tags: extjs, ext.net

Ext.Net Mvc 4.4 uses exjs 6.5.1 right? My question is: How can i use modern toolkit view in ext.net mvc 4.4 like these examples: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/kitchensink/?modern. I didn't find anything about these in http://mvc.ext.net/ examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.NET 4.4 only supports the *Classic* toolkit. The *Modern* toolkit is supported by http://mobile.ext.net/, but currently only incorporates Ext JS 6.0.2.